# Where do I type 'make config' to build a custom configuration?

Tags: kernel, updates, configuration

It is clear there are a couple different cool automagical processes taking care of the kernel on my Ubuntu machine.  One updates the kernel files on a regular basis, the other generates a new configuration and a new kernel and installs it.

When I read about configuring an ubuntu kernel, it says just cd to /usr/src/linux and type 'make config'.  That's not really a thing on my machine, unfortunately.

In /boot.there are a number of files neatly organized by release number.  In /usr/src, there are likewise a bunch of files named either "...header..." or "...hwe...", within which there are makefiles.

So if I go to one of these and touch ".config", then "make config"(or "make menuconfig", then "make install",
presumably I get a new set of kernel files in /boot.  But, if I don't want to jump right in and edit config files, some of which are machine generated from other files, etc.,
what do I do?

where do the header.$(uname -r) files come from?  If I want make linux.$(uname -r).myconfig, do I copy the files then run make config?  Or is there some mechanism that I can invoke to copy over the relevant pieces, then I cd and make config?  Also, do I make config in "headers" or in "hwe"?

Or do I cd to linux.$(uname -r), copy .config to .config.orig, then "make config" and somewhere in the process I get to tell it that it's not making "generic", but "myconfig"?

So I'm familiar with a bunch of the underlying tools like make, but there are obviously tools built upon those which do additional magic, and I want to get hold of them by the correct end, rather than plunging in mucking everything up.

If you don't feel like writing an essay, a reference to specific pieces of documentation would be great instead.

Thanks,

Doug

Comment: Hello. If you are not aware of how to even open a terminal may I suggest this is not something you should even be thinking about doing at this time.

Comment: I now how to open a terminal.  The question is in which directory do I run make config, and how do I create that directory so as to best mesh with the tools that are automaticallhy doing the other updates

Comment: Programming questions that have nothing to do with the Ubuntu OS.

Comment: They are about confiiguring and building a ubuntu kernel on an ubuntu macine.  It has everything to do with Ubuntu OS.